# How to filter on date and hour onward?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I've a simple data frame, and I need to filter every column from date: `2020-04-08` and hour `17` onwoards.

I've this:

```
bcp_desde_las_5 <- bcp %>%
                   filter(date == "2020-04-08" & hour == 17)
```

But it only returns data from that date and hour, not onwoards data as desired.

**UPDATE:**

The filter for hour should only apply to the first date: `2020-04-08`. It means that for that day I only need the data from 17 h to midnight.  But for every other date, I need every hour of the date.

Comment: Do you mean also the days after `2020-04-08` comprehensive of all the hours (0-24)?

Comment: @Ric S Yes, the hour filter should only apply to the first date, in this case: `2020-04-08`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to get the 'hour' greater than or equal to 17, then change the `==` to `>=`

```
library(dplyr)
bcp %>%
      filter((date == as.Date("2020-04-08") & hour >= 17)| 
             (date != as.Date("2020-04-08")))
```

Comment: Does it filter other dates and all the hours? or the filter for hour applies to other dates also? I would need to get the data for all hours for the other dates. So the hour filter should only apply to the date `2020-04-08`.

Comment: @OmarGonzales based on your comments, you may need a `|` condition

Comment: may you tell me the expressions before and after `|` are applied sequentially on the data frame? I don't get it because first you filter only date `2020-04-08` so this will mean you only have data for that date, so second expression should return 0 rows because you only have date `2020-04-08` and now you're excluding it.

Comment: @OmarGonzales it is an either OR condition which mean you are using `c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)|c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)` returns the rows where either one of the conditions are met

Answer (score 2):

In order to get every time point from `2020-04-08` and hour 17 onwards, you can use

```
library(dplyr)
bcp %>% 
  filter((date == as.Date("2020-04-08") & hour >= 17) | date > as.Date("2020-04-08"))
```

Comment: It works, but @Akrun answer seems more logic as he filters `2020-04-08` and hour greater than `17`, and then excludes that date. Makes more sense reading it. Well basically, both do the same. Thank you, Rick S.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but with `!=` you take also the dates before `2020-04-08`, right?

Comment: I was missing that part, but you can read akrun last comment on his answer. It made it clear to me, this is why you answer also works.

Comment: I read it, but with that expression you will pick up, for instance, a row that is `2020-04-07` at any hour, since it only says "different from `2020-04-08`

Comment: Oh wait, I read the update on your question. So you also need every date and every hour before `2020-04-08` too?

Comment: The first date on my df is `2020-04-08` so, I neded the rows from `2020-04-08` from 17 hrs onwoards, to last date and last hour available.

Comment: I see, your answer is superior in that regard as it wouldn't take any data before `2020-04-08`. Good catch!

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that, so I thought about an answer that could work with a generic dataset